# Why `after_save` not work when saving a copy data with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails version: 5.2.2.1

## DB

db/migrate/20190520050333_create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/20190520050350_create_post_copies.rb

```
class CreatePostCopies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :post_copies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## Model

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :save_post_copy

  private

  def save_post_copy
    if title_changed?
      post_copy = PostCopy.new
      post_copy.id = self.id
      post_copy.title = self.title
      post_copy.body = self.body
      post_copy.save!
    end
  end
end
```

## Console

```
post = Post.first
post.title = 'change title'
post.title_changed? # => true
post.save!

PostCopy.first
=> nil
```

Here want to auto save the record to `post_copies` when the `title` been changed in `posts`. But after the record saved in `posts`, can't find anything in `post_copies`.

Comment: You might want to check Papertrail gem, it is perfectly suited for monitoring changes to your records: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `id` should not be explicitly set, as rails automatically assign the value of the `id`

```
  def save_post_copy
    if self.title_changed?
      post_copy = PostCopy.new
      #post_copy.id = self.id
      post_copy.title = self.title
      post_copy.body = self.body
      post_copy.save!
    end
  end
```

Or alternatively

```
  after_save :save_post_copy, if: : saved_change_to_title

  def save_post_copy
    post_copy = PostCopy.new
    post_copy = self.dup
    post_copy.save
  end
```

Comment: `if title_changed?` not handled.

Comment: @02040402 should be `if self,title_changed?` , please have a look at given answer. let me know if it's working

Comment: @02040402 is your callback is not calling or record is not saving?

Comment: @Gabbar The same result. I added `Console` to the question.

Comment: @KetanMangukiya `if title_changed?` can't been known.

Comment: @02040402 HI, can you use this `saved_change_to_title` instead of `title_changed?`

Comment: @Gabbar Oh, it works! `saved_change_to_title`. Thanks! https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_change_to_attribute

Comment: @02040402 seems it's changed for new rails version. anyway glad to know that.